# Word difference and meaning?

Tags: word-meaning

Please tell difference between illusion and disillusion,I cannot understand it with the help of dictionary?i don't know how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions from Merriam-Webster make the difference quite clear:

[**Disillusion**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disillusion):

> the condition of being disenchanted

and *disenchanted* means:

> no longer happy or satisfied with something

[**Illusion**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illusion)

> - something that looks or seems different from what it is : something that is false or not real but that seems to be true or real
> - an incorrect idea : an idea that is based on something that is not true

So you can see that, though *disillusion* resembles *illusion* in spelling, but the meanings are completely different.

Comment: I think both the words have almost same meaning?can u tell me the difference precisely?

Comment: Well. An *illusion* is something that is **wrong, not true** while someone in *disillusion* is **unhappy, not satisfied**. So the real difference here is: untrue vs. unsatisfied. The first is something factual. Something is either true or not true. The latter is emotional. You *feel* dissatisfied.